# Incorrect sorting in Laravel and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm under the assumption others have faced this issue before, and maybe I am just using the incorrect terminology to search by in this instance. I have a table in my MySQL database where I want to pull the largest (highest or max) number in a column (not the main ID column though), however, it sorts like this:

- 1
- 101
- 102
- 2
- 22

And below is the image of my column. At this point, if someone has a suggestion just from a PHP/MySQL suggestion, I'm willing to take it and can go from there, however from the Laravel point of view, I am using:

```
$MaxProNo = DB::table('Shipments')->max('pro_number');
```

to pull that number.

[image: MySQL Database Table Column]

Comment: Is the `pro_number` column an `INT` or a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: At the moment it is text, though this was created by the person before me. Would you suggested changing the column from text to INT then? I have checked and all of the values are only numbers, so I am pretty sure no additional data would be lost

Comment: The problem is it is sorting them based on them being strings, if you change this to an `INT`, it should sort it out.

Comment: Ugh, thank you so much. I feel so stupid haha. I appreciate the help! Do you want to post your answer so I can accept it for you? Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, it's very easy to get blind to these things when you're working on something for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the format of your db column from `VARCHAR` to `INT`.